# Have a Lando web server listen on localhost:8000

Tags: lando

Long story, but due to previous configurations of 3rd party services, it'll be much easier if I can have Lando listen on port 8000 instead of the assigned docker port (e.g. it's different every time).  I've tried doing `overrides` such as

```
overrides:
  ports:
    - '8000'
```

Is it possible to configure Lando so that my apache server listens on port 8000?

Answer (score 0):

It is not an answer to your question, but if you use Lando proxy, you would not have a problem with changing appserver port and you can point your http request to the selected hostname.

Example of `.lando.yml`:

```
name: test

proxy:
  appserver:
    - test.localhost
    - my.local-domain.test
```